# bash variables - understanding scope after while loop

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop, pipe, subprocess

I have a trivial bash script as follows. It takes a csv file as the first parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash

x="John"
y="Dan"
z="Steve"

echo "x -- $x"
echo "y -- $y"
echo "z -- $z"

INPUT=$1
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 1; }
while read x y z
do
        echo "x: $x"
        echo "y: $y"
        echo "z: $z"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS

echo "x -- $x" #no value?
echo "y -- $y" #no value?
echo "z -- $z" #no value?
```

What I'm wondering is why will variables x, y, and z not hold ANY string values after the while loop runs? I understand that the while loop will change the value of x, y, and z locally. However, I expected x, y, and z to be "John," "Dan," and "Steve," respectively, after the while loop keeping their initially declared values. Or at the very minimum, hold the last values given to it by the csv parsing loop, rather than just empty.

Does the while loop create a subprocess of the original script context and then continue with that child process? Thanks in advance for the explanation.

**Edit #1**

Adding the csv file for context in case anyone wants to run it:

```
'P1','2014-10-31',0
'P1','2014-11-01',0
'P2','2014-11-07',0
'P2','2014-11-08',0
'P3','2014-11-14',0
'P3','2014-11-15',0
'P1','2014-11-21',1
'P1','2014-11-22',1
'P2','2014-12-05',1
'P2','2014-12-06',1
'P3','2014-12-12',1
'P3','2014-12-13',1
```

Comment: No. It replaces the contents of the global variables in your loop. If you want it to do otherwise put the loop in a function, and make the `x`,`y` and `z` `local`.

Comment: As an aside, you don't have to save/restore IFS.  Call your read like this: while IFS=, read x y z to set it for the while only.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if it replaces the global variables, why aren't they set to the values in the last line of the csv file at the end of the script? They are simply empty.

Comment: Because the end of the csv file causes the script to set the *global variables* empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what is going on here is that the read fails, and populates the variables with nothing at the end of the while loop.  They still should be in scope.

Clarification:
The read fails when it tries to read and there is nothing left to read when it has reached the end of the file.  At this point, the while loop exits and the variables are cleared (although the variables are still in scope).

Comment: Actually, I checked, and `read` will clear the value of its variables even if it reads no input: `x=3; read x < /dev/null` will set `x` to the empty string.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Of course read fails, otherwise while loop would run forever.

Comment: Documentation isn't clear (even checking the POSIX specification), but `read` seems to set the variables named by its arguments to the null string before attempting to read from its input. This is confirmed in several versions of `bash` as well as `dash`.

Comment: I don't think the read is failing. So are you saying 'read' will simply remove the variable values all together? Or wouldn't it just set the variables to the last line of the csv file (added for context)?

Comment: @chepner, I guess that, regardless of success or failure, `read` will set the variables to whatever it has read so far (here, it reads nothing). Try: `read a < <(printf '%s' "hello"); echo "$?"; echo "$a"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That sounds better. Reading at the end of the file "reads" an empty line, and after processing that, `read` exits with status 1.

Answer (score 3):

The `while` statement (and the `read` command that it executes) are executed in the same shell. However, `read` will set the values of `x` et al. to whatever it reads, including the empty/null line that it sees at the end of the input which causes it to exit with non-zero status.

If you want to preserve the values of the variables when no input is available, you'll have to use different variables in the `read`, and set `x` et al. in the body of the loop.

```
while read a b c; do
    x=$a
    y=$b
    z=$c
done < "$INPUT"
```

Now, `a`, `b`, and `c` are still global variables as well, but `x`, `y`, and `z` are only modified when `read` succeeds.